# How to export a .mat file full of characters to a .txt file?

Tags: matlab, text, text-files

I am trying to export a .mat file full of characters into a .txt file. Part of the .mat file looks like the following:

zentimeter
zepler
zero
zeros
zeroth
zeta
ziel
zig
zigxag
zimmermann
zinc
zirconate
zisler
zncl
zns
zobel
zobels
zodiacal
zolatarev
zonal
zone
zones
zurich

After loading it to the workspace, I tried save command but it did not work and later I tried the command:  `[row]=find (dictionary)`. Instead of displaying the characters, a lot of numbers were displayed. May I know how to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's data format is binary.  You can cycle through the cells and use `fprintf` to print to a file.